# Can I Install Debian 64 bit on RPi 3

Tags: debian, pi-3, 64-bit

The Raspberry Pi 3 is built with a 64 bit chip. Yet the Raspberry Pi Foundation has only released Linux distros are 32 bit.

Can I install a 64-bit version of Debian on the RPi 3?

Answer (score 6):

Not unless you have a 64 bit version compiled for the ARM architecture. You can't install the AMD64 or x86-64 version as the architecture is different.

Quoting from the Pi Foundation's blog post [announcing the Pi3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-3-on-sale/):

> At launch, we are using the same 32-bit Raspbian userland that we use on other Raspberry Pi devices; over the next few months we will investigate whether there is value in moving to 64-bit mode.

The switch to a 64 bit processor was primarily because of the gains it provided in clock speed.

Comment: So I guess the answer is *not yet* but I can't believe that there won't be an enterprising developers out there who will put together build a cross-compiling tool-chain on non-Pi hardware - or will the absence of 64-bit versions of the non-free bits (the binary blobs loaded in at start-up) be an issue?

Comment: @SlySven I agree this will come to pass, I don't think the binary blobs will pose a problem but I can't say for sure.

Comment: I was just reading the other day that `config.txt` is supposed to have a setting now that tells the binary blob whether it should be instantiating the processor with 64bit support or not. I'll post later if I can find the source.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Debian 7 (wheezy) or Debian 8 (jessie) support the Raspberry Pi3 in AArch64 mode. Debian 9 (stretch) will very likely support the Pi3 in 64bit mode , though. Progress can be monitored here: https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi3

Comment: very good news, the debian team is preparing it. @steve-robillard - isn't there some synergy with both?

Comment: The only thing you'd need to get [Debian's Arm64 port](https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64Port) working would be a 64-bit Pi kernel -- which has been compiled if you search around, although I dunno if it comes out fully functional.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't wait for the official stretch release you can take a look at the [pi64 image on GitHub](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64). It is basically a Debian stretch with the raspberry kernel.

> pi64 is an experimental 64-bit OS for the Raspberry Pi 3. It is based
>   on Debian Stretch and backed by a 4.11 Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps - you can download and use free for a year (requires registration) the "Evaluation copy of SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2 for Raspberry Pi" - [here](https://www.suse.com/eval/download/?build=ccUe-rz974A~&event_id=DGSLE12SP2&event_name=Eval%3A%20SLES%20Raspberry%20Pi&icid=GSDGNEval23017&icname=Eval%3A%20SLES%20Raspberry%20Pi%20Nurture&login_required=1)

Answer (score 0):

They've been working on it for a few years, I was running an earlier version a year ago.  But see https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi3

It's not completely up to Debian release standards so they're still calling it a preview (unofficial, unsupported, etc.).  It's Debian Buster.