# How to install hhvm in raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian

My pi already setup and update with raspbian debian 8
But i can not install hhvm even add source deb to `etc/apt/source.list.d/hhvm.list`
Pi said can't locate hhvm package
How to install hhvm

Comment: Please explain about what you have so far attempted. I see that you state your inability to "add source deb" may you please elaborate on the error that you receive and the steps needed to reproduce said error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install HHVM on any version of the Raspberry Pi. According to the installation documents (specifically regarding [compiling from source](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/building-from-source)), you need a 64 bit operating system.

If you can get a 64 bit operating system running on the RPi 3, you may have a chance, but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi 3 appears to support an [arm64 architecture.](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi3)

If using a Raspberry Pi 3 or more recent, you might want to try to [compile HHVM on arm64.](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-14.04-%28arm64%29)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a 64-bit ARM (`AArch64`) OS build for HHVM as well as 64-bit hardware.

Raspbian is 32-bit and Linux support is very much "experimental" where it is present.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73255/8074 says there a Pi64 build of Debian 9.  Patches were uploaded by Suse for hardware support, and [Arch Linux seems to have a build](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3).

FreeBSD 12 is looking a bit better (and has the benefit of not being Linux) as it has an `arm64/rpi3` image, more info on that is available in the [FreeBSD Wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/arm64/rpi3).