# Is there a way to install "true" debian on a Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: debian

I've read that in contrast to older Raspberry Pis, the Raspberry Pi 3 is a true armhf system, and one can use "regular" debian.

How would on do so practically (setting up bootloader etc.)

Comment: related http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43588/19949

Comment: There's some ambiguity in the term "armhf".  Debian and other distros use this to refer to ARMv7+ systems, since early ARMv6 did not include hardware floating point ("hf") support.  The Pi 2 and 3 are included in the "ARMv7+" category, but *all* earlier models of Pi are in the category of later ARMv6 which *does* have hf -- hence Raspbian made the confusing but not inaccurate choice of using `armhf` to refer to their packages.  So you're wrong; all pi's are "true armhf" systems.  However, the 2 and 3 and the only ones currently capable of running ARMv7 software ("armhf" in Debian-speak).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know what you're doing, you should always use the Debian images provided by the Raspberry Pi foundation. The provided images are tailored for the Raspberry Pi so unless you want to roll your own distribution (for educational purposes, for instance), there's no reason not to stick with these.